# How to Connect Windows CE Device through network using active sync

Tags: windows-xp, windows-ce, activesync

I am trying to connect an **Windows CE 5.0** device through a cradle that **only has an ethernet output** to an **XP machine**. I am **currently using a network crossover cable** but I cannot seem to find out how to do this.

Which version of active sync should I be using? and how do I do this?

Any advice would be great!

Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC ActiveSync non longer supports network connectivity